# Heroku app insisting on HTTPS - why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, ssl, heroku

I have an interesting little problem - an app on Heroku is configured to use [Heroku SSL (beta)](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ssl-beta) but it seems to want to use HTTPS for everything, nomatter what I do.

#### Browser Error:

I have `redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently` on one controller. Requests to this controller get:

```
www.mysite.com redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

#### Relevant code:

DNS settings:

```
ftp: www.mysite.com.herokudns.com
www: www.mysite.com.herokudns.com
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'rack-ssl-enforcer'
gem 'rack-cors'
```

production.rb:

```
** Not in effect**
#config.force_ssl = true
```

application.rb:

```
# Note: no code inserted for rack-ssl-enforcer

config.middleware.insert_before 0, 'Rack::Cors' do
  allow do
    origins '*'
    resource '*', headers: :any, methods: [:get]
  end
end
```

#### My attempt to avoid HTTPS on one controller:

requests_controller.rb:

```
before_action :avoid_ssl

def avoid_ssl
  if request.ssl? && Rails.env.production?
    redirect_to :protocol => 'http://', :status => :moved_permanently
  end
end
```

The code I most recently added to `requests_controller.rb` has initiated this error. Something in my app is wanting everything to be HTTPS, but Heroku support told me:

"There's nothing special about Heroku SSL, redirects have to be performed inside your application - to skip 'force SSL' for a given controller it's a code change".

What could possibly be causing everything to direct to HTTPS? Thank you very much.

Comment: Check that your browser is not redirecting because of previous HTST. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security

Comment: @SimoneCarletti That was it! Thank you. Feel free to leave an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that your browser is not redirecting because of a previous [HSTS header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security).

When you enable `force_ssl` on Rails, the middleware automatically appends the header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security
```

with an expiration of 1 year. If you then disable it, your browser will keep the information stored until the expiration and will refuse to connect to the HTTP version of the site anyway.

You can remove the setting from your browser. However, please note that any user that previously accessed your website will be affected by the same behavior as this is the purpose of the HSTS header.

Therefore, in order to maintain compatibility with users who visited the site previously, you should still provide the HTTPS version and avoid sending the HSTS header (or setting it to a very short expiration).